# What does "would get back to you" actually mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions, meaning-in-context

Some days ago I sent an email with an attachment. The recipient replied with the following sentence.

**Thanks for kindly sending your profile information. I would get back to you as soon as possible.**

What does this reply email mean?
What is the actual meaning of **I would get back to you as soon as possible**?

Comment: It's likely that he chose the wrong word and probably meant "I will get back to you as soon as possible," a common enough response. However, this sentence is possible: I would get back to you as soon as possible if I weren't undergoing surgery.

Answer (score 1):

"would get back to you" means that he/she will contact you again.

In your sentence, he meant that he has some stuff to do, and then he will contact you again after that.